# Builds failing on tfs because workspace cannot be populated with files that the changeset deletes

Tags: tfs, build

I've made a change to MyBranch of MyProject, which I'm trying to build on TFS.
`These changes include deleting the folder "Source-deleted"`
I've tried shelving it and building that and I've also tried a [Gated Check-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx).
However it failed both times with a Activity Log that looked like this:

```
Overall Build Process
Update Build Number
Run On Agent (reserved build agent MyBuild01 - Agent3)
Create Workspace
Get Workspace
 The item $/MyProject/MyBranch/Source-deleted has not been mapped.
 The item $/MyProject/MyBranch/Source-deleted/Clients has not been mapped.
  etc etc

  Exception Message: TF400889: The following path contains more than the allowed 259 characters:
 D:\Builds\7\MyProject\Dev_Nightly\Sources\__Unmapped__\12077\\Source-deleted\Clients\  #### etc #### \somthing.datasource.
 Specify a shorter path. (type InvalidPathException)
```

Previous builds have shown nothing under the get workspace item (ie they have just worked) and I don't believe its anything wrong with my changes per se, rather its to do with all the files that exist in latest that are delete in my shelve-set.
 I've looked in my build folder on the branch and I don't think there's anything that refers to these files and folders.

What is going on? `Has anyone seen builds on tfs failing because of deleted files?`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look in your build definitions source control mappings.

I would guess that

> The item $/MyProject/MyBranch/Source-deleted has not been mapped. 
>   The item $/MyProject/MyBranch/Source-deleted/Clients has not been
>   mapped.

is not included in your source code mappings, either temporarily include these mappings and do the build, or swap the trigger type to manual / CI to do your check in.

You usually get this type of error on a gated build when files that are outside of the workspace scope are included in the check in.

[image: Source Settings tab]

You need to ensure that your workspace included the files you need, you need to ensure that your files are covered. The above just shows the source settings tab.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "temporarily include these mappings"? By my build def's source control mappings do you mean "Projects to Build"?

Comment: "temporarily include these mappings" : set the mappings for this checkin only, if the folder is to be deleted.    source control mappings : Source Settings 3rd tab down in the build definition. Ensure that source settings covers "$/MyProject/MyBranch/Source-deleted"

Comment: "You usually get this type of error on a gated build when files that are outside of the workspace scope are included in the check in."  Thank you for that tidbit.  Now I get it.  In my case I was doing a big Forward-Integration and some of the code was outside the "Source Control Folder" path (as you point out).  But I was at a loss before finding this.  Thanks again.